# Display Android Webview in a square shape

Tags: android, layout, webview

I'm trying to get a webview to maintain a perfect square shape on any phone.  Below is my current layout code... It works on some phones.. but smaller ones the height is not as big as the width (causing the image in from the website being viewed to be distorted).

Thanks in advance for any help.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="#ffffffff"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal|center"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_weight="1">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/wvGif"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#ffffffff"
        android:isScrollContainer="false"
        android:scrollbars="none" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use this method. Change size programatically. It works.

```
 Display display= this.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
int width = display.getWidth();

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams;

            layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams((int) (width * ((float) 1 / 2)), (int) (width * ((float) 1 / 2)));
            webView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following to get any device's height and width and then use this data to specify the height & width of your view.

```
Display mDisplay = activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
final int width  = mDisplay.getWidth();
final int height = mDisplay.getHeight();
```